# Are there any good podcasts in Hebrew?

Tags: hebrew, adult-learning

One of the things I'm missing in the US is lack of easy access to spoken modern Hebrew. Can anyone recommend a good podcast featuring news (as well as possibly other subjects) in Hebrew for offline listening? So far, I've only found a handful of podcasts on Hebrew learning and on religious studies, whereas I'm really looking for something beyond that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: welcome to Judaism.SE! I'm not sure if this question is in scope here. I wonder what the community thinks. [Here's](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/162/in-what-respects-are-hebrew-language-questions-in-scope) the relevant meta deliberation.

Comment: Streetwise Hebrew on TLV radio. Among other things, I used SH to get nearly fluent in conversational Hebrew without any official classes.